# A STL-like vector implementation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors

I'm implementing a STL-like vector with the essential functionalities.

I would like to know what is good in this code and what is bad. In terms of everything (memory usage, functions implementations, naming conventions, etc,...).

The header:

```
#ifndef BVECTOR_H
#define BVECTOR_H

#include <memory>

static const int MIN_CAPACITY = 16;
static const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
static const int SHRINK_FACTOR = 4;

class BVector
{
public:
    BVector() = delete;
    BVector(int);
    BVector(int, int);
    //BVector(const BVector&); //Copy Constructor
    //BVector(const BVector&&); //Move Constructor

    //BVector& operator=(BVector&); //Copy assignment operator.
    //BVector& operator=(BVector&&); //Move assignment operator.

    ~BVector() = default;

    int const& operator[] (int) const;
    int& operator[](int);
    int at(int);

    void push(int);
    int pop();
    void insert(int, int);
    void prepend(int);
    bool find(int);
    void Delete(int idx);

    int size() const;
    int capacity() const;
    void resize(int);
    bool isEmpty();


private:
    int m_size{0};
    int m_capacity{MIN_CAPACITY};

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> m_data;

    int DetermineCapacity(int);
    void IncreaseCapacity();
    void DecreaseCapacity();
};



#endif // BVECTOR_H
```

The implementation:

```
#include "bvector.h"
#include <iostream>

BVector::BVector(int capacity): m_size(0)
{
    int new_capacity = DetermineCapacity(capacity);
    m_data = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[new_capacity]);
}

BVector::BVector(int capacity, int init_val)
{
    int new_capacity = DetermineCapacity(capacity);
    m_data = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[new_capacity]);

    for(int i = 0; i < new_capacity; i++)
    {
        m_data[i] = init_val;
    }
}

int const& BVector::operator[](int idx) const
{
    return m_data[idx];
}

int& BVector::operator[](int idx)
{
    return m_data[idx];
}

int BVector::at(int idx)
{
    return m_data[idx];
}

void BVector::resize(int requiredSize)
{
    if(m_size < requiredSize)
    {
        if(m_size == m_capacity)
            IncreaseCapacity();
    }else if(m_size > requiredSize)
    {
        if(m_size < (m_capacity/SHRINK_FACTOR))
           DecreaseCapacity();
    }

}

int BVector::DetermineCapacity(int capacity)
{
    int actual_capacity = MIN_CAPACITY;

    while(capacity > (actual_capacity/GROWTH_FACTOR))
    {
        actual_capacity *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
    }

    return actual_capacity;
}

void BVector::IncreaseCapacity()
{
    int old_capacity = m_capacity;
    int new_capacity = DetermineCapacity(old_capacity);

    if(new_capacity != old_capacity)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> new_data = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[new_capacity]);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            new_data[i] = m_data[i];
        }

        m_capacity = new_capacity;

        m_data = std::move(new_data);
    }
}

void BVector::DecreaseCapacity()
{
    int old_capacity = m_capacity;
    int new_capacity = old_capacity / 2;

    if(new_capacity < MIN_CAPACITY)
        new_capacity = MIN_CAPACITY;

    if(new_capacity != old_capacity)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> new_data = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[new_capacity]);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            new_data[i] = m_data[i];
        }

        m_capacity = new_capacity;

        m_data = std::move(new_data);
    }
}

int BVector::capacity() const
{
    return this->m_capacity;
}

int BVector::size() const
{
    return this->m_size;
}

void BVector::push(int val)
{
    resize(m_size + 1);
    m_data[m_size] = val;
    ++m_size;
}

bool BVector::isEmpty()
{
    return (m_size == 0);
}

int BVector::pop()
{
    if(!this->isEmpty())
    {
        resize(m_size-1);
        int value = m_data[m_size];
        --m_size;
        return value;
    }else
    {
        std::cout << "Nothing to pop." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void BVector::insert(int value, int idx)
{
    resize(m_size + 1);

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> newData  = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[m_capacity]);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size+1; i++)
    {
        if(i == idx)
        {
            newData[i] = value;
            newData[i+1] = m_data[i];
        }
        else if(i > idx)
        {
            newData[i+1] = m_data[i];
        }
        else
        {
            newData[i] = m_data[i];
        }
    }

    m_data = std::move(newData);

    ++m_size;
}

void BVector::prepend(int value)
{
    resize(m_size + 1);

    for(int i = m_size; i > 0; i--)
    {
        m_data[i] = m_data[i - 1];
    }

    m_data[0] = value;

    ++m_size;
}

bool BVector::find(int reqVal)
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        if(m_data[i] == reqVal)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void BVector::Delete(int idx)
{
    resize(m_size - 1);

    for(int i = idx; i < m_size - 1; i++)
    {
        m_data[i] = m_data[i+1];
    }

    --m_size;
}
```

The usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bvector.h"

int main()
{
    BVector vec(10);

    std::cout << vec[3] << std::endl;

    vec.push(10);
    vec.push(20);
    vec.push(30);
    vec.push(40);
    vec.push(50);
    vec.push(60);
    vec.push(70);
    vec.push(80);
    vec.push(90);
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(110);
    vec.push(120);
    vec.push(130);
    vec.push(140);
    vec.push(150);
    vec.push(160);
    vec.push(170);
    vec.push(180);

    vec.insert(333, 8);

    vec.Delete(8);

    std::cout << vec[vec.size()-1] << std::endl;

    vec[vec.size()-1] = 555;

    std::cout << vec.at(vec.size()-1) << std::endl;

    vec.prepend(987);

    std::cout << vec.at(0) << std::endl;

    std::cout << vec.at(1) << std::endl;

    int x = vec.pop();

    std::cout << "Popped Value: " << x << std::endl;

    bool flg = vec.find(150);
    std::cout << flg << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Any detailed notes is so much appreciated.

Comment: STL-like? Some parts of it are somewhat similar to a specific instantiation (`std::vector<int>`), but there are more differences.

Comment: If it's meant to be STL-like, I'd at least expect it to satisfy requirements of [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container), be usable with algorithms, range-based for, etc... The interface should similar too, there are many odd names in your case.

Comment: It also has no [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

Comment: A good read for sobody implementing the vector. I wrote four articles on how to do it. [Vector - Resource Management Allocation](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/index.html) [Vector - Resource Management Copy Swap](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/29/vector-resource-management-ii-copy-assignment/index.html) [Vector - Resize](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/12/vector-resize/index.html) [Vector - Simple Optimizations](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/19/vector-simple-optimizations/index.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your two constructors don't store a value into `m_capacity`, so if the initial capacity requested (passed in as a parameter) is larger than the default capacity you'll have things in an inconsistent state and likely run into problems later.

Is there a reason you're not using `std::make_unique<int[]>`, instead of allocating memory with `new` and constructing a `unique_ptr` from it?

`at` member functions in the standard containers will perform bounds checking.  Your `at` does not.

Is there a particular reason you're exiting the program if you detect a problem, rather than throwing an exception?

`DetermineCapacity` can enter an infinite loop if the `actual_capacity *= GROWTH_FACTOR` calculation overflows.

`IncreaseCapacity` and `DecreaseCapacity` are almost identical.  Their functionality can be placed into a common function to avoid the code duplication.

You don't need to use `this->` in member functions like `capacity` and `size`.

In `pop`, you need to read the value to return *before* you shrink the array.  Since your resizing can reallocate memory and copy the vector contents, this can result in your reading an invalid value.

Why is `insert` *always* doing a reallocation?

`Delete` does not validate its argument, which can lead to Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Several of the public member names differ needlessly from those of the standard containers.  That can prevent use of this class in generic code.

For instance,

> ```
> void push(int);
> int pop();
> void prepend(int);
> bool isEmpty();
> ```

I would have expected:

```
void push_back(int);
void pop_back();
void push_front(int);
bool empty() const;
```

These ones, dealing with size and capacity, should normally use `std::size_t` rather than `int`:

> ```
> int size() const;
> int capacity() const;
> void resize(int);
> ```

It's also worth providing the standard type definitions that generic code expects of a container (`value_type`, `size_type`, etc).

We really, *really* need iterators for the collection.  Then we wouldn't need `find()` to be a member, because `std::find()` does that job.  `insert()` and `erase()` also normally accept iterators rather than indices.

There's lots of unnecessary loops where standard algorithms could and should be used (`std::fill()` and `std::move()` in particular).

I don't see why capacity calculation needs a loop.  Just add the headroom to the required capacity rather than iterating over a fixed sequence of sizes.

Libraries shouldn't write, especially to standard output (`std::cerr` is the appropriate place for error messages), and certainly shouldn't terminate the process (except perhaps if specifically built for debugging, with `NDEBUG` undefined).

Answer (score 3):

```
static const int MIN_CAPACITY = 16;
static const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
static const int SHRINK_FACTOR = 4;
```

Global `const` variables automatically get internal linkage, thus making the `static`s redundant.

Since you tagged your question [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), the preferred way is to use `constexpr` variables:

```
constexpr int MIN_CAPACITY = 16;
constexpr int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
constexpr int SHRINK_FACTOR = 4;
```

Also, all-capital words are usually for macros.